# Setting up an online store with only one product

Tags: e-commerce

I've been asked to set up a site to sell a single product online, and that's all there'll ever be.

I don't want a CMS; it's a 4 page site and I'll be doing any admin myself so a CMS is completely unnecessary.

I've been playing with zen cart, but the whole "you need to register before you purchase" nonsense is a bit of a deal breaker.  Besides that, installing a shopping cart for a single product just seems like overkill.

I don't want to suggest to the client they use a subscription service like shopify.

This is the 2nd site in 3 weeks that I've been asked to do something like this. The first time I just used the seller's merchant paypal account, but I need to find a better solution.

Has anyone any suggestions? I need to get this puppy up by Friday so time is ticking.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why isn't a PayPal button good enough?

Comment: Well, as I said, I did that the last time so it's "ok". But I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my most recent project, I built a site that sells a single product and/or a subscription to said product. We've used [Amazon Payments](https://payments.amazon.com/). You could also check out [Google Checkout](http://checkout.google.com), if you're averse to PayPal.

Comment: Well, I ended up hacking the crap out of the CSS on Opencart. Nothing else seemed to fit with what I needed, but your suggestion is a valid one.

Comment: Here's a recommendation: generalize all your hacked CSS/HTML, re-package it, and you can share (or sell) your experience and material to people in a similar predicament.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you checkout FatFreeCart.com?  Its a free eCommerce option that allows you to take payments through PayPal or Google Checkout, and you do not have to signup for anything to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Ecwid. It is a simple solution from same guys who make X-Cart. Hosted on Amazon EC2, installs in 5 minutes.